# find boot and shutdown times for a time period

Tags: 20.04

I need to on a daily basis see my ubuntu boot up and shut down times for the past 24 hours

1.
I used to be able to view the system boot and shutdown times for the past 24 hours from the Logs app but since running Stacer it now only shows the last boot up time (maybe running stacer and the logs app acting different is just coincidence ? ).
If it is Stacer that changed the Logs app display, does anyone know how to change it back to displaying boot and shutdown times for the past 24 hours.

2.
Can i using the Terminal display a list of boot and shutdown times for the past 24 hours

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

At a teminal type `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i shutdown`
For older syslog type `cat /var/log/syslog.1 | grep -i shutdown`
And you can swap out the word **shutdown** for other words like **boot** etc.

Comment: darth_epoxy, thanks, your answer sort of worked but gave me more than i needed, but googling  your suggestion led me to these two terminal inputs (below) that come closer to what i wanted, wouls still be nice to have a list for just the last 24 hours but will do.<br/>


To show listing of last reboot.<br/>
last reboot<br/>


To show listing of last shutdown.<br/>
last -x | grep down<br/>